# Magento 2 add Dropdown Quantity Box In Checkout Cart Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, qty

I am trying to replace Drop-down instead of text box at Quantity at Checkout cart page.

How can i override

/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Add checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml to your module

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default" as="default" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple" as="simple" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> And Add default.phtml

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/cart/item**

**default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Files.LineLength.MaxExceeded

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper(Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data::class);
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Item')) ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else :?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                </a>
            <?php else :?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else :?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()) :?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) :?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])) :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['full_view']) ?>
                                <?php else :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span', 'a']) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()) :?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message) :?>
                        <div class= "cart item message <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($message['type']) ?>">
                            <div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                    <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Price')) ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('See price before order confirmation.')) ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map"
                       id="<?= ($block->escapeHtmlAttr($helpLinkId)) ?>"
                       data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{
                                            "helpLinkId": "#<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($helpLinkId)) ?>",
                                            "productName": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($product->getName())) ?>",
                                            "showAddToCart": false
                                            }
                                        }'
                    >
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("What's this?")) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else :?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Price')) ?>">
                <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <div class="control qty">
                    <label for="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                        <span class="label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
                            <select id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                                    name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                                    data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                                    data-role="cart-item-qty"
                                    class="input-text qty select_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"
                                    >
                                 <option  value="1" <?php if($block->getQty() == 1){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >1</option>
                                 <option  value="2" <?php if($block->getQty() == 2){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >2</option>
                                 <option  value="3" <?php if($block->getQty() == 3){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >3</option>
                                 <option  value="4" <?php if($block->getQty() == 4){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >4</option>
                                 <option  value="5" <?php if($block->getQty() == 5){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >5</option>
                                 <option  value="6" <?php if($block->getQty() == 6){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >6</option>
                                 <option  value="7" <?php if($block->getQty() == 7){echo "selected='selected' "; } ?> >7</option>
                              </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else :?>
                <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

> **After add this files please run Magento upgrade commands.**

***I Hope This Helps You.***